# MySQL aggregate report

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

I am trying to build a query that will return aggregated sales data. My current query returns a table similar to this:

```
----------------------------------
| DATE       | SKU      | TOTAL  | 
----------------------------------
| 2014-11-10 | AV155_A  | 209.00 |
| 2014-11-10 | AV155_B  | 627.00 |
| 2014-11-10 | AV155_C  | 279.00 |
| 2014-11-10 | AV155    | 279.00 |
| 2014-11-10 | AV1556_A | 209.00 |
| 2014-11-10 | AV1556_B | 627.00 |
| 2014-11-10 | AV1556_C | 279.00 |
| 2014-11-10 | AV1556   | 279.00 |
```

However, instead of having a total for each individual SKU, I would like an aggregated total that matches each SKU with the same 'parent sku.' In this example, I would like two results, one aggregating the total for 'AV1555' and one aggregating the total for 'AV1556.' The table should look something like this:

```
-----------------------------------
| DATE       | SKU      | TOTAL   | 
-----------------------------------
| 2014-11-10 | AV1555   | 1394.00 |
| 2014-11-10 | AV1556   | 1394.00 |
```

The query I am currently using looks like this:

```
select
  DATE_FORMAT(created_on, '%m-%d-%Y') as date,
  sku,
  SUM(price) as total 
FROM order_items
WHERE created_on between FROM_UNIXTIME(1415577600) AND NOW()
GROUP BY MONTH(created_on), DAY(v.created_on), order_item_sku;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want is `substring_index()`:

```
select DATE_FORMAT(created_on, '%m-%d-%Y') as date,
       substring_index(sku, '_', 1) as sku_prefix
       SUM(price) as total 
FROM order_items
WHERE created_on between FROM_UNIXTIME(1415577600) AND NOW()
GROUP BY date(v.created_on), substring_index(sku, '_', 1);
```

You should also include the year in the `group by` (which is done by including the whole date).  It might not be needed today, but it might prove useful just three or four weeks from now.

Comment: @SQLHacks . . . Your answer is correct as the OP originally phrased it.  S/he revised it slightly and you definitely do not deserve a downvote for it.

Answer (score 0):

You can aggregate on LEFT(sku,6)

```
select
  DATE_FORMAT(created_on, '%m-%d-%Y') as date,
  LEFT(sku,6),
  SUM(price) as total 
FROM order_items
WHERE created_on between FROM_UNIXTIME(1415577600) AND NOW()
GROUP BY MONTH(created_on), DAY(v.created_on), LEFT(sku,6);
```

If your sku can be variable length you could use

```
select
  DATE_FORMAT(created_on, '%m-%d-%Y') as date,
  LEFT(sku,LEN(sku)-2),
  SUM(price) as total 
FROM order_items
WHERE created_on between FROM_UNIXTIME(1415577600) AND NOW()
GROUP BY MONTH(created_on), DAY(v.created_on), LEFT(sku,LEN(sku)-2);
```

However you have some examples with non-child skus and that makes it a whole lot harder...

Comment: That works great! However, what if my SKUs are variably lengths? (they are, and I'll update my sample table to reflect than)

Comment: There are a bunch of string functions in MySQL. How do you spot the child skus?

Comment: Child skus always have an underscore and then a letter